# Want to create a custom controller

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-custom-resources

I'm here to ask for a help. I want to create a `custom controller` for my `custom resource` and literally I have no idea how and from where to start, like from where `golang` script will run for `controller` and how my `custom resource` will be useful.

So, I need some help with how I can start and from where I should start.

Thanks in advance

Deepak

Answer (score 1):

When using Go, the [kubebuilder](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder) is a good start for creating Kubernetes controller and custom resource. [The Kubebuilder online book](https://book.kubebuilder.io/) is a good tutorial to follow, to learn the components of the controller and the kubebuilder SDK.

Comment: Let me give you an example. Suppose I created a custom resource under a namespace called slacknotification and it has one parameter 1. slack_webhook_url. Now, what it should do, every time when image tag is changed in deployment then it should send me a notification on slack that my previous tag was this and new tag is this.Pardon me but it's just an example, so how can I achieve this. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere or any improvement is required. Thanks in advance because I am very new in this

Answer (score 0):

As Jonas suggested you can go for **Kubebuilder** or **[Operator SDK](https://www.velotio.com/engineering-blog/getting-started-with-kubernetes-operators-golang-based-part-3)** is also a good option.

i won't suggest writing the custom controller until it's not required as you have now to manage the code, versions etc.

Instead you checkout the existing controller or application like the [Kubewatch](https://github.com/vmware-archive/kubewatch), which also do the same job for you.

**Kubewatch** check the K8s events and based on that send the slack message.

Checkout my article : https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/kubernetes-event-notifications-1b2fb12a30ce

If you have a requirement to write custom code you can simple make own Deployment with client library, which will look for the event of K8s

Check out my Github repo : https://github.com/harsh4870/Slack-Post-On-POD-Ready-State

Which checks for the **POD ready** statement and sends the slack notification, you can re-write that **python** code to **Go** as per need.